# Variables not passing through with AHK

Tags: variables, syntax, autohotkey

Basically I have a code the relies on a global variable and then saves it's value into a local variable in order to remember what it used to be after it is changed. However it is simply not passing through for some reason...

The problem is that PrevSlot returns blank and does not save CurrentSlot's value

```
CurrentSlot := 3

NumpadDot::
PrevSlot := %CurrentSlot%
    if (CurrentSlot != 0) {
        PrevSlot := %CurrentSlot%
        CurrentSlot := 0
        CurrentSlotName := "0_QuickLaunchMenu.ahk"
        ;MsgBox, , Title, "Quick Launch Menu", 1

        IfWinExist, FileList[PrevSlot]
        {
            WinClose ; use the window found above
        }

        IfWinNotExist, "QuickLaunch.ahk"
            {
                Run, % A_WorkingDir "\QuickLaunch.ahk"
            }

        if not GuiActive
        {
            displayGui(500)
        } else {
            Gui, Destroy
            GuiActive := 0
            displayGui(0)
        }
    } else {
        CurrentSlot := %PrevSlot%
        CurrentSlotName := FileList[PrevSlot]
        ;MsgBox, , Title, "Quick Launch Menu", 1

        IfWinExist, "QuickLaunch.ahk"
        {
            WinClose ; use the window found above
        }

        IfWinNotExist, FileList[PrevSlot]
            {
                Run, % A_WorkingDir "\NumbpadLayouts\" FileList[PrevSlot]
            }

        if not GuiActive
        {
            displayGui(500)
        } else {
            Gui, Destroy
            GuiActive := 0
            displayGui(0)
        }
    }
return
```

Full Code

```
    #NoEnv  ; Recommended for performance and compatibility with future AutoHotkey releases.
; #Warn  ; Enable warnings to assist with detecting common errors.
SendMode Input  ; Recommended for new scripts due to its superior speed and reliability.
SetWorkingDir %A_ScriptDir%  ; Ensures a consistent starting directory.
DetectHiddenWindows, On
SetTitleMatchMode, 2

CurrentSlot := 2
CurrentSlotName := "Media"
FileList := []
GuiActive := 0

Loop, Files, %A_WorkingDir%\NumbpadLayouts\*.ahk
   FileList.Insert(A_LoopFileName)

; Iterate from 1 to the number of items:
;Loop % FileList.MaxIndex()
;    MsgBox % FileList[A_Index]

; Enumerate the array's contents:
;For index, value in FileList
;   MsgBox % "Script " index " is: '" value "'"
;return

IfWinNotExist, FileList[CurrentSlot]
{
    Run, % A_WorkingDir "\NumbpadLayouts\" FileList[CurrentSlot]
}

;============================== [ Page Controls ] ==============================
NumpadMult::
;MsgBox, , Title, Current Slot: %CurrentSlotName%, 1
displayGui(0)
return

NumpadDiv UP::
    if (CurrentSlot > 1) {
        PrevSlot := %CurrentSlot%
        CurrentSlot -= 1
        CurrentSlotName := FileList[CurrentSlot]
        ;MsgBox, , Title, Current Slot: %CurrentSlotName%, 1

        IfWinExist, FileList[PrevSlot]
        {
            WinClose ; use the window found above
        }

        IfWinNotExist, FileList[CurrentSlot]
        {
            Run, % A_WorkingDir "\NumbpadLayouts\" FileList[CurrentSlot]
        }
     } else {
        PrevSlot := %CurrentSlot%
        CurrentSlot := FileList.MaxIndex()
        CurrentSlotName := FileList[CurrentSlot]
        ;MsgBox, , Title, Current Slot: %CurrentSlotName%, 1

        IfWinExist, FileList[PrevSlot]
        {
            WinClose ; use the window found above
        }

        IfWinNotExist, FileList[CurrentSlot]
        {
            Run, % A_WorkingDir "\NumbpadLayouts\" FileList[CurrentSlot]
        }
    }
    if not GuiActive
    {
        displayGui(500)
    } else {
        Gui, Destroy
        GuiActive := 0
        displayGui(0)
    }
return

NumpadSub UP::
    if (CurrentSlot < FileList.MaxIndex()) {
        PrevSlot := %CurrentSlot%
        CurrentSlot += 1
        CurrentSlotName := FileList[CurrentSlot]
        ;MsgBox, , Title, Current Slot: %CurrentSlotName%, 1

        IfWinExist, FileList[PrevSlot]
        {
            WinClose ; use the window found above
        }

        IfWinNotExist, FileList[CurrentSlot]
        {
            Run, % A_WorkingDir "\NumbpadLayouts\" FileList[CurrentSlot]
        }
    } else {
        PrevSlot := %CurrentSlot%
        CurrentSlot := 1
        CurrentSlotName := FileList[CurrentSlot]
        ;MsgBox, , Title, Current Slot: %CurrentSlotName%, 1

        IfWinExist, FileList[PrevSlot]
        {
            WinClose ; use the window found above
        }

        IfWinNotExist, FileList[CurrentSlot]
        {
            Run, % A_WorkingDir "\NumbpadLayouts\" FileList[CurrentSlot]
        }
    }
    if not GuiActive
    {
        displayGui(500)
    } else {
        Gui, Destroy
        GuiActive := 0
        displayGui(0)
    }
return

;============================== [ Quick Launch ] ==============================
NumpadDot UP::
PrevSlot := CurrentSlot
    if (CurrentSlot != 0) {
        ;PrevSlot := %CurrentSlot%
        CurrentSlot := 0
        CurrentSlotName := "0_QuickLaunchMenu.ahk"
        ;MsgBox, , Title, "Quick Launch Menu", 1

        IfWinExist, FileList[PrevSlot]
        {
            WinClose ; use the window found above
        }

        IfWinNotExist, "QuickLaunch.ahk"
            {
                Run, % A_WorkingDir "\QuickLaunch.ahk"
            }

        if not GuiActive
        {
            displayGui(500)
        } else {
            Gui, Destroy
            GuiActive := 0
            displayGui(0)
        }
    } else {
        CurrentSlot := %PrevSlot%
        CurrentSlotName := FileList[PrevSlot]
        ;MsgBox, , Title, "Quick Launch Menu", 1

        IfWinExist, "QuickLaunch.ahk"
        {
            WinClose ; use the window found above
        }

        IfWinNotExist, FileList[PrevSlot]
            {
                Run, % A_WorkingDir "\NumbpadLayouts\" FileList[PrevSlot]
            }

        if not GuiActive
        {
            displayGui(500)
        } else {
            Gui, Destroy
            GuiActive := 0
            displayGui(0)
        }
    }
return

QuickLaunchFunction(slot)
{
    global

    if (CurrentSlot = 0) {
        if (slot <= FileList.MaxIndex()) {
            ;local PrevSlot := %CurrentSlot%
            CurrentSlot := slot
            CurrentSlotName := FileList[CurrentSlot]
            ;MsgBox, , Title, Current Slot: %CurrentSlotName%, 1

            IfWinExist, FileList[local PrevSlot]
            {
                WinClose ; use the window found above
            }

            IfWinNotExist, FileList[CurrentSlot]
            {
                Run, % A_WorkingDir "\NumbpadLayouts\" FileList[CurrentSlot]
            }
            if not GuiActive
            {
                displayGui(500)
            } else {
                Gui, Destroy
                GuiActive := 0
                displayGui(0)
            }
        } else {
            MsgBox, , Title, %slot% doesn't exsist, 1
        }
    }
}
;============================== [ Numberpad QuickLaunch Keys ] ==============================
Numpad0::
QuickLaunchFunction(0)
return
Numpad1::
QuickLaunchFunction(1)
return
Numpad2::
QuickLaunchFunction(2)
return
Numpad3::
QuickLaunchFunction(3)
return
Numpad4::
QuickLaunchFunction(4)
return
Numpad5::
QuickLaunchFunction(5)
return
Numpad6::
QuickLaunchFunction(6)
return
Numpad7::
QuickLaunchFunction(7)
return
Numpad8::
QuickLaunchFunction(8)
return
Numpad9::
QuickLaunchFunction(9)
return

;NumpadEnter::
;NumpadAdd::

;============================== [ Functions ] ==============================
displayGui(length)
{
    global
    if not GuiActive
    {
        GuiActive := 1  ;Sets the GuiActive status to active (Aka the gui is currently being displayed)

        CustomColor = 000000    ;Can be any RGB color (it will be made transparent below).
        Gui +LastFound +AlwaysOnTop -Caption +ToolWindow    ;+ToolWindow avoids a taskbar button and an alt-tab menu item.

        ;Gui, Add, Picture, x40 y40 w80 h80 , %Numpad7Img%  ;Adds Gui Image
        Gui, Add, Text, x10 y5 w220 h25 , %CurrentSlotName%


        ;Gui, Color, %CustomColor%
        ;WinSet, TransColor, %CustomColor%

        Gui, Show, x1740 y1015 h25 w220 NoActivate  ; NoActivate avoids deactivating the currently active window.

        if (length > 0)
        {
            sleep, %length%
            Gui, Destroy
            GuiActive := 0  ;Sets the GuiActive status to inactive (Aka the gui is currently not being displayed)
        }
    } else {
        Gui, Destroy
        GuiActive := 0  ;Sets the GuiActive status to inactive (Aka the gui is currently not being displayed)
    }   
}
```

Comment: `PrevSlot := %CurrentSlot%` gets the value of variable whose name is in `CurrentSlot`. With `:=` you don't need percent signs. See also [autohotkey assign a text expression to a variable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17498698)

Comment: Hello again wOxxOm! I tried without the % and it still does not pass through. Ill give you the whole code to give you some better perspective and maybe something else is at play but I just don't get it. For example I have other hotkeys that have very similar functions and the variables pass through them fine so I'm really unsure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I played around with it and I made PrevSlot a global variable and removed the % around the variable.